# OpenVPN command line installation

Tags: powershell, cmd, openvpn

I'm new to powershell, I have been tasked in pushing out a scrip to install OpenVpn to our remote offices, Firstly I wanted to install the OpenVpn on my own computer using that same script.

I have found this tutorial https://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/command-line-installation-of-openvpn/ so far but i'm not sure how to perform this task. the /SELECT_..command is not a cmdlet.

Not sure if this is meant to be made into an executable file.

Comment: Hi.  Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Please edit the question and copy/paste the code you are trying to make work. Include any error messages. Tell what it is doing and what it should do.

Comment: Sorry guys for not making it very clear.  I'm trying to download OpenVPN using windows PowerShell , once the executable file has been downloaded i need it to be installed silently. the goal is to push the said script onto other laptops. I cant really post post any error messages as ive only this to work with, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your link told about you have some EXE file installer, and from promt you must run it with keys like:

```
openvpninstaller.exe /S /SELECT_SERVICE=1  /SELECT_OPENSSLDLLS=1
```

Run it in promt and you succesfull install it.  /SELECT_.. - are properties for executable file.

Comment: Thank you Vad for the explanation, The installation did take place as you have mentioned but the challenge now is to download the openvpninstaller.exe file using a script, I have downloaded it manually in order to test the scrip provided by you, I downloaded the .xe file using the following link. https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/

Comment: For script donwload just use:


`$url="https://swupdate.openvpn.org/community/releases/openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win10.exe"

$outputlocation="d:\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win10.exe"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outputlocation`